# jQuery toggle links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle the classes on a couple of links. Consider the following mark up:

```
<ul class="inline toggleNav">
    <li><a class="active" id="imagesLink" href="#">Images</a></li>
    <li><a class="noLink" id="desLink" href="#">Description</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the following jQuery:

```
$('.noLink').click(function(){
    $('.active').addClass('noLink');
    $('.active').removeClass('active');         
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).removeClass('noLink');
 });
```

Now this will swap the classes one way but not both ways? So when I click Description the classes swap but when I click Images after that nothing happens?

Comment: If you want to toggle classes, why not use `.toggleClass()`?

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are binding event only once and only on the `.noLink` link when the page load (so 'images' has no event).

You should use delegation instead of direct binding :

```
$('.toggleNav').on('click', '.noLink', function(){})'
```

If you dont want to use delegation, you'll need to bind event on every `a` and use this code :

```
$('.toggleNav a').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).is('.noLink')) return;
    $('.active').addClass('noLink');
    $('.active').removeClass('active');         
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).removeClass('noLink');
 });
```

Which can be reduced to :

```
$('.toggleNav a').click(function(){
    if($(this).is('.noLink'))
        $('.toggleNav a').toggleClass('active noLink');
 });
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/F5ZSA/9/

Comment: Really? Delegation is not always needed, is it?

Comment: I believe in this case, it is needed

Comment: @JayBlanchard Of course, there is an other solution without using delegation, but you would have to change OP code.

Comment: He is not dynamically adding the links to the DOM, they exist and only need their classes changed.

Comment: @JayBlanchard i know that, added a solution without delegation.

Answer (score 2):

When you bind the `click` handler, you're only binding it to the elements that have `noLink` class when the page is loaded. Since you're changing classes dynamically, you need to use event delegation so that the bindings will follow the changing classes.

```
$(".toggleNav").on("click", ".noLink", function(){
    $('.active').addClass('noLink');
    $('.active').removeClass('active');         
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).removeClass('noLink');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    <ul class="inline toggleNav">
    <li><a class="" id="imagesLink" href="#">Images</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="" id="desLink" href="#">Description</a>
    </li>
     <li><a class="" id="desLink" href="#">test</a>
    </li>
     <li><a class="" id="desLink" href="#">1</a>
    </li>
</ul>

    $("a").click(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('noLink');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    if ($("a").not(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $("a").not(this).removeClass('active');
        $("a").not(this).addClass('noLink');
    }
   else {
        $("a").not(this).addClass('noLink');
    }
 });
```

Example is here:[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/z7RS3/)

Comment: Thanks for the solutions. Many ways to do this. It might be worth noting that these links will also show hide 2 content divs depending on which is pressed.

Comment: I guess I can do something like this:

   $('#show2').click(function(){
        $('#slide1').hide();
       $('#slide2').fadeIn(2000);
    });   
    
   $('#show1').click(function(){
        $('#slide2').hide();
       $('#slide1').fadeIn(2000);
    });

Comment: Very true.. It's all about logic :)

Answer (score 0):

You have [`jQuery.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) for that exact need:

```
$( "#foo" ).toggleClass( className, addOrRemove );
```

Equals to

```
if ( addOrRemove ) {
  $( "#foo" ).addClass( className );
} else {
  $( "#foo" ).removeClass( className );
}
```